# PHP dump all data if script tries to allocate more than allowed memory

Tags: php, memory

Is there any way I can dump all variables with their values a script has into a file when the script tries to allocate more memory than it is allowed to? For debugging purposes.

Comment: How you are limiting youer memory ? thru `php.ini` ??

Comment: @Makesh Yes, with memory_limit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
register_shutdown_function('shutdownFunction');
function shutDownFunction() {
    if ($error['type'] == 1) {
        // do your stuff here
    }
}
```

It will be called when running into your fatal error.

Comment: Dear god I completely forgot about shutdown functions :X